# Need help figuring out what the Problem with fgets is

Tags: c, null, fgets, file-pointer

So basically I have a file-pointer to a file that has 80 digits between 0 and 1 and I need to get them into a string to then do something with it.

The function returns `NULL`, and I cannot find what's wrong because if it returns `NULL` it just means error.

```
    FILE *fpr = fopen(path, "r");
    FILE *fpw = fopen("code.txt", "w");
    char *str = calloc(81, sizeof(char));
    if (fpr == NULL || fpw == NULL) {
        printf("yikes");
    }
    if (fgets(str, 80, fpr) != NULL) { //HERE ITS NULL
        int p1 = 0;
        int p2 = 0;
```

I really thought it through and im either really dumb or there is no obvious problem.

Comment: `if (fpr == NULL || fpw == NULL) {` You ignore this and try to use `fgets` on a possible `NULL` fptr. You should have `return` or `exit`.

Comment: Check if 'path' contains the path AND file name.

Comment: Does it print `"yikes"`?

Comment: If `yikes` doesn't print, it could also means your file is empty, or there's an error condition (check `ferror()` to validate that).

Comment: You don't see the "yikes" because you don't have the newline `\n` at the end.

Comment: @SamySmart: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score

Answer (score 3):

The are a few problems in the code fragment:

- if any of the files cannot be open, you still call `fgets()`, which has undefined behavior if `fpr` is `NULL`. Make a separate test for each `FILE*`, print a more explicit error message and exit the program.
- you should pass the size of the array to `fgets()`, `81` instead of `80`.
- the array should be allocated to at least 82 bytes: 80 characters plus the trailing newline and a null byte terminator.
- you do not test for memory allocation failure. You should not even allocate memory, a local array is OK for a small size like 82 bytes.

Here is a corrected version:

```c
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>

    ...
    char str[82];
    FILE *fpr = fopen(path, "r");
    if (fpr == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open input file %s: %s\n", path, strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }
    FILE *fpw = fopen("code.txt", "w");
    if (fpw == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open output file %s: %s\n", "code.txt", strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }
    if (fgets(str, sizeof str, fpr)) {
        int p1 = 0;
        int p2 = 0;
        ...
```

Always test error conditions and print explicit error messages, you will safe yourself countless hours of debugging time.